# Java ScheduledThreadPool multithreads stops after some time

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling, executorservice

I´m developing a J2SE app that sync GPS information of 184 cars stored at four databases on differents servers. For every car I create a Thread and stored in a ScheduledThreadPool

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
        Car vec_temp = cars.get(i);
        SyncThread carThread = new SyncThread(q, vec_temp, reintentos);
        long sleep = carThread.calculateVehicleDelay();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(hilo, 0, sleep, MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

Information of Latitude and Longitude is retrieved by a SocketServer in XML data, so inside the SyncThread Class I instanciate a Socket and ask for information and close that connection, and make this every 15 minutes...

The app start working great for some reason at some time stops running with no Exception ...

The jar is running as a windows service.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29),

> If any execution of the task
>   encounters an exception, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed.

That being said, it would be nice if you posted the code inside `SyncThread`, otherwise it'll be nearly impossible to help you. Also, what's `hilo`? Why are you scheduling `hilo` to be executed, rather than `carThread`?

Comment: SyncThread just simply connects to a socket server kkSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
  out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream())); them output a message and receive a new response message and finally close the connection... and do this every 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Try putting up a try-catch block in your Runnable implementation. Idea is to suppress any exceptions from being thrown out to the executor. Ideally, if you could log this incident in your catch block and avoid throwing it out, your application should work as expected, and you will be able to identify what happened afterwards.

Comment: Ok Yohan I tried that and throws this java.lang.Exception: Connection timed out: connect it seems to be the socket connection any idea ?

Comment: @marman Yes. That means a network connection that you try to establish gets timed out because the other end does not respond in time as expected.